# Como detectar si selecciono 2 veces la misma imagen react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, funciones, eventos

tengo un problemita con las imagenes se ilustra mejor.
Slecciono una imagen, y esta se muestra
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
luego cambio el estado de la imagen con un select en el modal pero esto no cambia el event del onChague, en la consola se ve que sigue siendo el mismo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Mi problema es que ya que actualice el estado de la imagen esta ya no es la del event y pues si lo vuelven a seleccionar no se muestra, como hago para que el se dispare apesar de que seleccione la misma imagen...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto solo ocurre cuando selecciono una imagen, luego actualizo el estado y en este estado trato de asignar la misma imagen pues ya no se dispara, creo que es por que en el event esta almacenada la que ya cargue.

```
 const onFileChange = (event) => {

        let x =  event.target.files[0];

        setcambios({x});
        console.log('doble',event.target.files[0]);
        // setMensajeData({...MensajeData, imageTemplate:'null'});
        // console.log(imagen,"<--- onchangueFile antes de usar set, dataMensaje--->",MensajeData);
        setImagen({...imagen,imageTemplate: event.target.files[0]});
        handleFileSelect(event.target.files[0]);
        // console.log(imagen,"<--- onchangueFile, dataMensaje--->",MensajeData);
        event='vacio';
  

    };

    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var file = evt; // FileList object
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
          return function(e) {
            var binaryData = e.target.result;
            var base64String = window.btoa(binaryData);
            setMensajeData({...MensajeData, imageTemplate: base64String});
          };
        })(file);
        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
      }
```

Comment: Te sería más fácil validar los nombres de las imágenes que ya tienes cargadas, y de ahí tomar la decisión de ignorarla o mandar un mensaje diciendo que ya existe.